# Вывод с многомерного массива javascript значений в select

Tags: javascript, массивы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, делаю фильтр подбора, создал массив, в котором значения id, name, marka. Почему-то в select не выводятся значения, раньше делал через ajax + php всё работало. Нужно, чтобы в select передавались значения marka. Вот код:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  {literal}

  let json = [{
      "id": "999",
      "name": "Toyota",
      "marka": [{
          "Camry": {
            "url": "https:/category/camry/"
          }
        },
        {
          "Crown": {
            "url": "https:/category/crown/"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "998",
      "name": "Honda",
      "marka": [{
          "Camry": {
            "url": "https:/category/camry/"
          }
        },
        {
          "Crown": {
            "url": "https:/category/crown/"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]

  {/literal}
</script>

<div class="filtr__container">
  <p class="filtr__container-title">Подбор аккумуляторов</p>
  <select class="filtr__select" id="idcat">
    <option id="marka-avto">Выберите марку авто</option>
  </select>

  <select class="filtr__select" id="idcat2">
    <option id="model-avto">Выберете модель авто</option>
  </select>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    {literal}
    json.forEach((item) => {
      $('#idcat').append('<option value="' + item.name + '">' + item.name + '</option>');
    });

    $('#idcat').change(function() {
      var val = $(this).val();
      $('#idcat2').html('');
      var data = {
        'marka': val
      };

      function(data) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
        obj.forEach(function(item) {
          $('#idcat2').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", item).text(item));
        })
      }
    });
    $('#idcat2').change(function() {
      var val = $(this).val();
      var data = {
        'url': val
      };

      function(data) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
        obj.forEach(function(item) {
          $('#redirect').attr("href", item);
        })
      }
    });
    $('#redirect')
    {/literal}
  </script>
  <a id="redirect" type="submit" name="submit" value="Кнопка" style="display: flex;height: 38px;background-color: #FF4900;justify-content: center;align-items: center;color: #fff;border-radius: 5px;margin-top: 14px;font-size: 16px;text-decoration: none;">Подобрать</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Что это за `function(data) {`?

Comment: Это был ajax код, я его переделал, возможно не правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мда, закручено по-полной.

1. Поправил Ваш код, чтобы отступы были нормальными.
2. Определитесь с данными: где у Вас марка, а где модель машины. Марки у Вас вроде как "Toyota" и "Honda". А модели - "Camry" и "Crown". Давайте соответственно переименуем элементы данных

---

```
{
  "id": "999",
  "marka": "Toyota",
  "model": [
    {
      "Camry": {
        "url": "https:/category/camry/"
      }
    },
    {
      "Crown": {
        "url": "https:/category/crown/"
      }
    }
  ]
},
```

3. Я бы советовал использовать словари вместо массивов.

---

```
let json = {
  "Toyota": {
    "id": "999",
    "models": {
      "Camry": {
        "url": "https:/category/camry/"
      },
      "Crown": {
        "url": "https:/category/crown/"
      }
    }
  },
  "Honda": {
    "id": "998",
    "models": {
      "Camry": {
        "url": "https:/category/camry/"
      },
      "Crown": {
        "url": "https:/category/crown/"
      }
    }
  }
```

4. Блоки `function(data) {...}` просто объявляют функцию - и тут-же забывают её, так как Вы не присваиваете результат в переменную. Могло бы быть так:

---

```
let myFunction = function(data) { ... }
myFunction(data);
```

Но на самом деле Вы просто должны выкинуть строки обрамления `function(data) { ... }`, а содержимое `...` - оставить

5. Что такое `{literal}` и `{/literal}` - этого я не знаю, может какой-то шаблонизатор? Но тут им не место

В итоге можно предложить такой код:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  let json = {
    "Toyota": {
      "id": "999",
      "models": {
        "Corolla": {
          "url": "https:/category/corolla/"
        },
        "RAV4": {
          "url": "https:/category/rav4/"
        }
      }
    },
    "Honda": {
      "id": "998",
      "models": {
        "Camry": {
          "url": "https:/category/camry/"
        },
        "Crown": {
          "url": "https:/category/crown/"
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<div class="filtr__container">
  <p class="filtr__container-title">Подбор аккумуляторов</p>
  <select class="filtr__select" id="idcat">
    <option id="marka-avto">Выберите марку авто</option>
  </select>

  <select class="filtr__select" id="idcat2">
    <option id="model-avto">Выберите модель авто</option>
  </select>

  <a id="redirect" type="submit" name="submit" value="Кнопка" style="display: flex;height: 38px;background-color: #FF4900;justify-content: center;align-items: center;color: #fff;border-radius: 5px;margin-top: 14px;font-size: 16px;text-decoration: none;">Подобрать</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  Object.keys(json).sort().forEach((item) => {
    $('#idcat').append('<option value="' + item + '">' + item + '</option>');
  });

  var marka;

  $('#idcat').change(function() {
    marka = $(this).val();
    if (json[marka]) {
      $('#idcat2').html('');
      var obj = json[marka].models;
      Object.keys(obj).sort().forEach(function(item) {
        $('#idcat2').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", item).text(item));
      });
    } else {
      $('#idcat2').html('<option id="model-avto">Выберите модель авто</option>');
    }
  });

  $('#idcat2').change(function() {
    var model = $(this).val();
    var obj = json[marka].models[model];
    $('#redirect').attr("href", obj.url);
  });

  //Не знаю зачем это здесь - закомментировал
  //$('#redirect')
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое